# Can I connect to SQLite DB on Android Emulator from within Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, android-emulator, maui

I want to access a SQLite database that I've created in my MAUI app on the Android Emulator from within Visual Studio.

I added the SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox extension to Visual Studio 2022, but I can't browse to the Emulator file system to read from it. How can I access the file system of the emulator from windows?

Or is there another way to go about connecting to the SQLite database?

Comment: you need to use the Android `adb` tools to copy the files from the emulator to your desktop

Comment: @Jason that answers my question. Kind of a duh moment there. I haven't messed with adb since trying to Root my old Nexus 5. Thanks!